# GUI 2D curves to normalice values , change values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, opencv

I'm looking for a way to find a 2d curve interface  that goes from 0 to 255 values to change the brightness value of an image, something we see very often in graphic packages.

[image]

I haven't found anything made in python for graphics, maybe I don't know how to search well.

The closest thing is this example. or this example.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cahqdxeshd

Someone has some information about how to do it in python

Comment: See Catmull-Rom splines at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull–Rom_spline and http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/nsp/course/15-462/Fall04/assts/catmullRom.pdf  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251438/catmull-rom-splines-in-python and https://github.com/vmichals/python-algos/blob/master/catmull_rom_spline.py and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: Thank you I will revise all the links. I can't understand that there is no library of curve handles to normalize and alter values. That it has to be programmed from 0. reggards