# Extract coordinates between each control point of a Catmull-Rom spline

Tags: javascript, python, extract, points, cubic-spline

I'm generating a *2D centripetal Catmull-Rom spline* in JavaScript from random control points on a `canvas`. My intent is to be able to extract a certain defined number (say 10) of intermediate points between the control points of the spline, exactly as requested and solved in [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95195/how%20-to-get-coordinate-from-spline-interpolation) found post dedicated to the *Mathematica* software.

In my case I would need to generate them via pure *JavaScript* or *Python* scripting, so I would to know if there is a way to convert those Mathematica's commands with some JavaScript or Python module/framework, thank you.

Comment: You might check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251438/catmull-rom-splines-in-python

Comment: Thank you, @TimRoberts, I will give a more in deep look to it! Found this resource too, for now: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10432

Comment: Just another resource to test, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850845/how-to-extract-points-from-a-graph